# Get source code of telegram bot built with Manybots

Tags: telegram-bot

My client built a Telegram bot using a builder bot "Manybots".
Now he wants me to improve his bot and host it on his webserver.

How can I get the source code for this bot? I tried contacting Manybots but had no reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

short answer: you cannot. They didn't even reply to my message. I rebuilt the bot from scratch, which didn't take long anyway